# Number sequence in AXAPTA

Tags: axapta

I have created new LeaveMaster table in Axapta. please let me know how can i create number sequence of LeaveID. please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa608474(v=AX.50).aspx) on MSDN that explains how to create your own custom number sequence. If you want to use an existing number sequence, use the [NumberSeq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa618982(v=AX.50).aspx) class by calling `NumberSeq::newGetNum()` or `NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode()`.